# Extract first words from a nvarchar in column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have original col in some pattern like this :

```
myWord xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx
```

I would extract `myWord` and changed like this :

```
myNewWord xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for the first word by searching for the first space (`' '`). Then split the string using `RIGHT` and concatenate that to the `'myNewWord'`:

```
WITH Tbl(col) AS(
    SELECT 'myWord xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'first xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sample xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx'
)
SELECT  *,  
    NewCol = 'myNewWord' + RIGHT(col, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX(' ', col) +1)
FROM Tbl
```

Comment: @aziz This assumes that the string has a space. Modify it to your liking.

Comment: yes . i have a col of letterDate like "one January two thousand" want changed to "FIrst January two thousand"